# While geting the file response from Api i can get the total property of the event

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is what I am doing to call the api

```
const url = `http://localhost:5005/call/http://localhost:5009/api/Results/export`;
    console.log('before calling api', this.value);
    return this.http.post(url,QueryObject,{
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
        observe: 'events',
        reportProgress: true,
    })
    // this.dataService.exportAllComments()
    .subscribe((event: any) => {
      console.log(event);
      console.log('right after subscribe', this.value);
}, (err:any) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.loadingFile = false;
    });
```

Here is the response I get

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Don't you want to `observe: 'response'` instead of `observe: 'events'`?

Comment: when i use event response i get an empty result